# Simple ViewController / View, remove white bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am just looking at setting up a simple viewController programatically, I have a ViewController.xib file that I have set the background color to RED in interface builder. I have also added the following to my AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation syntax_MapViewAppDelegate
@synthesize window;

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    viewController = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:[viewController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

When I run the code it does what I expect apart from the white bar at the bottom of the screen, can anyone give me any pointers in how to remove this? I have a feeling I might need to position the view within the window, but I am not sure how?

[image]

cheers Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set your view frame.

```
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,20.0,320.0,460.0);
```

Now the view cover your full screen with Red color.

You can also set it from interface builder as well.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, how do you set this from interface builder?

Comment: If your view size is going to be fixed through out application lifetime then you can set the frame property of view from Interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might save your problem:

```
[[viewController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
```

Comment: Here will be larger than screen as you are specifying the height as 480 because we are already taking 20 pixels of top bar into consideration.

Comment: @Jim: you're absolutely correct. It's a mistake make by habit, taking the screen's height as 480. I'm correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

Set your view  to resize dynamically using the autoresizingMask or set it's frame explicitly.